# What do you call a person who is in some danger and needs help?

Tags: single-word-requests

A person who rescues someone in danger is called a saviour. What is the person who needs help from this saviour called?

Comment: Please sort out the mismatch here. 'Needs help' or 'receives help'?

Comment: "Needs help". I mean looking for help.

Comment: That is different from both the questions you've asked so far.

Comment: Received help: The rescuee Is rescued by the rescuer/savior. Needs help: victim. Looking for help? Possibly victim, could just be a leech/mooch.

Comment: It would also help if we knew what kind of trouble this person were in. "Saviour" has a lot of religious connotations which may defeat the purpose of your word usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth's answer of *imperiled* fits the best, so far. But it looks like the question was edited to remove the suggestion of the person having already received help, which invalidates most of the answers so far. (Perhaps the question should be closed? Is there a close category for a question morphing from A to B?)

Comment: @Drew Actually, it started as A / B (non-identical), which happens all too often (the title question not an exact match of what follows), _then_ morphed to C. This _does_ need addressing on meta.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I added a [question on meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/5252/51214) about it. But it seems like the question is not site-specific. Probably somone will point out that the question is a duplicate...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Persons who are not yet rescued and are in need of help' are **imperilled**.

Comment: +1 This captures "in danger* very well. It does not necessarily capture "needs help" (does not imply that any help is feasible). But I don't know of a word that captures both parts of the request.

Comment: Yes; OP gave two non-identical questions and then switched to a third. I'm tempted to suggest 'insegrevious', which means whatever you want it to.

Comment: (Meta) I'm thinking such moving-target questions should perhaps be closed. Or at least downvoted (because poorly expressed or unclear). They certainly should not be encouraged. People spend time & effort trying to help with a moving target. That just turns off helpers, and that hurts the site and users generally.

Answer (score 2):

"The **rescued** were airlifted to Calgary's Foothills hospital."

As well, "saviour" is a very strong word with Christian overtones; it is usually only used in extreme and or life-threatening situations, or if the speaker/writer is pumping up the rhetoric a bit. **Rescuer** is more neutral and usual.

**Victims** may also be used in some situations, especially if crime or human agency caused the danger.

Answer (score 2):

Someone who needs help is ***helpless*** because they are unable to help themselves. You can denote that they are in danger in the context.

Example:

> On his way home from Singapore, after temporarily stopping his ship, the captain, age fortyfour, radioed his superior, asking permission to rescue these helpless people.
>
> [The Storm of Our Lives: A Vietnamese Family's Boat Journey to Freedom *By Tai Van Nguyen* (2009)]

You can also consider ***desperate***:

> desperate - a person who is frightened and in need of help; "they prey on the hopes of the desperate"
>
> <sup>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/desperate</sup>

Example:

> Whether at work rescuing down pilots during combat or stranded hikers in the mountains, the PJs, along with the rest of the rescue units, are often the last hope for desperate people.
>
> [Careers in the National Guards' Search and Rescue Units *By Meg Greene* (2002)]

Answer (score 1):

**Victim** seems likely (even if only a *victim of circumstances*) for those who both "will require" and "have required" saving.

Another possibility might be to refer to the person as "the **innocent**" or "the **unfortunate**" (meaning one who is in a bad situation not of their own making) but that would not apply in all circumstances (ex: the man who climbs a powerline tower and is in danger of electrocution is not an innocent).

Comment: FWIW, I would not say that everyone in danger and who needs help is a *victim*. A victim is more likely to be someone who has already suffered something. (Same comment as for @WillHunting, since same answer wrt *victim*.)

Answer (score 0):

They are often referred to as being a person **in harm's way**: [liable to be harmed; subject to potential causes of harm](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+harm's+way)